# Firefox addon to print / download directly from tab into a specific location

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I would like to know if it's possible to develop an addon for Firefox (min version 60) which allows user to download / print direcly in pdf or png an active tab in a **specific folder**(absolute path outside from the download folder). 
The folder could be chosen in the addon's options and the user will only have to click on the addon's icon.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to find an additional Extension API for your functionality. You can use the regular Javascript method `window.print()` in your content script file to print/download the currently active tab. Tested it on both Chrome and Firefox. Should work fine.